# To what degree the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics is tested?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

I am not sure the question is well posed, what I mean is sort of an experiment in which one extracts some random, say, uniform distribution out of a quantum processes, and tests to what degree that sequence is indeed uniformly random.

I am curios, since I have never heard an opinion that the quantum random outcomes are results of some pseudo random cause, say coupling of some fundamental quantity (time, space) with process that generates pseudo random results (say, average entropy in the universe).